# angular reactive form validation template parse error

Tags: angular, angular-template

[image]I am trying to validate the form which is throwing template parse error. In the below code {{elments.key}} will be string getting from json after iterating the json using for loop. I am trying to concantenate a invalid ,touched ,error validate classes to it . But it is throwing an error, i understood that i am making an error in syntax. Help me in to get through it . Thanks in advance.

```
    <div class="{{elements.key}}.invalid"></div>
    <div *ngIf="{{elements.key}}.invalid && ({{elements.key}}.dirty || {{elements.key}}.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">

      <div *ngIf="{{elements.key}}.errors.required">
        {{elements.validationMessage}}
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible app in Stackblitz?

Comment: @Shravan i have created a stackblitz link , please remove the commented line and check .

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7q9bux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html